# have a same class name issue in two different java files

Tags: java

i have two java files named OverloadCons.java and OverloadCons2.java both containing two classes each. one class for the main method named OverloadCons/OverloadCons2 in both files and the other class is named Box in bothe the files i compiled and it worked perfectly but how can it work when both files contain same class named Box(not conatining the main method)

Comment: What is the package ?

Comment: From the question, it sounds like it's working fine, and the asker just wants to know why

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza *"and it worked perfectly"*

Comment: Is this `Box` class inside your `OverloadCons`/`OverloadCons2` class or outside of it?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: *"i have two java files named OverloadCons.java and OverloadCons2.java both containing two classes each [...] and the other class is named Box"*

Comment: @m0skit0 if the java files have no package declared then this works with no problem. Since OP hasn't defined this, I can't say your answer is 100% accurate.

Comment: It will work no matter the package. There's a different Box class **inside** each of the Java classes OverloadCons and OverloadCons2. I don't think he means wrapped, but inner class or declared in the same .java (thus private).

Answer (score 4):

Because one is `OverloadCons.Box` and the other is `OverloadCons2.Box`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for essentially the same reason that you can have multiple classes each have the same function (eg toString() or the like)

Since they have different outer classes, there's no overlap

Answer (score 0):

When you have compiled both the files it must be looking like this(ie, only one box.class class file)
[folder containing your files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e63aQ.png)

[image]

Now the Box.class file here contains the code for the **most recent file**(Overloadingcons.java or Overloadingcons2.java) **that has been compiled**.

for example - if you compiled Overloadingcons2.java most recent and try to run Overloadingcons.java then class Box which was written in Overloadingcons2.java will get executed.

hence now if you have this kind of situation then you must compile and execute the file together , otherwise it won't work properly every time.